# Passing data from a form to a table on another page (html)

Tags: javascript, html

Good morning/afternoon,
I'm attempting to create a html website for people to participate in a psychological study. It is mostly created, however, I cannot move any **form** data to my **table** in the results page. In addition, I've tried to automatically add a ne row to the table every time a participant enters their data in. I've started with the "age" and "gender" fields with no luck. I want to do this for two more pages but I haven't bothered since I cannot get these two to work. I've tried multiple sources but have come empty-handed. If anyone can give me a solution, it would be helpful.

P.S.: I'm currently using Sublime Text 4, but I've also used Visual Studio Code.

Link to video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eV-tf-W2rQ&t=184s

Link to multiple videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0ihEHxd6vI&list=TLPQMjIxMTIwMjFNmOKj8JKu0A&index=1

Here is the html code for my form and the javascript for the submit code:

[image: Form html code]

[image: Submit js code]

And here is the html of the results page, wth some css and javascript:

[image: Results page with js script]

Comment: [Never post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+pass+data+from+html+page+to"html+page+%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Also this has nothing to do with the editor you are using and it seems you are not using a server process, so the PHP tag is also irrelevant

Comment: PHP IS relevant if you want to SAVE the results to be viewed by others, but then you need to [search for that instead](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+save+form+on+server+site:stackoverflow.com)